# how to write content of a session to database just before expiring-MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

In my MVC application i have some session variables. and i want to store the content of session to database before the session expires. How can i catch an event to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global.asax

```
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //save to db
}
```

Comment: Becareful, often Session_End does not get called if your server is not happy - so this is only of use for data that is not inportant to the user.